# Setting ringtone for Alarms

Tags: android

I am been stuck , while developing an alarm based application on android.
Currently my alarm is firing correctly.But i have kept a toast, to notify the alarm.

I want to use ringtone for alarm notification.

Can anyone, help me out with this.

Rgds
Yaaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MediaPlayer` to play your ringtone whenever you feel like it.